# When i try to get the id of each tap i get only the Id of the last Tab

Tags: android, android-volley, android-tablayout

[json data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCNtg.jpg)I'm loading tab names from json and when i try to get the data about each tab i get only the data about the last rab only 
here is the code

```
final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    final RequestQueue catRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    JsonArrayRequest catJsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, Utils.BASE_URL + "getCats"
            , null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    categoryModel.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    categoryModel.setId(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(categoryModel.getName()), false);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catId = categoryModel.getId();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    catRequestQueue.add(catJsonArrayRequest);
```

CategoryModel class

public class CategoryModel implements Serializable{

```
private String id;
private String name;
private String parent;
private String photo;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(String parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public String getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto(String photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}
```

}

edit

```
categoryModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    final RequestQueue catRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    JsonArrayRequest catJsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, Utils.BASE_URL + "getCats"
            , null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    categoryModel.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    categoryModel.setId(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                    categoryModelArrayList.add(categoryModel);
                    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(categoryModel.getName()), false);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    catRequestQueue.add(catJsonArrayRequest);
```

Comment: "When i try to get the id of each tap i get only the Id of the last Tab" - You're updating `catId` each time through the loop - `catId = categoryModel.getId();` - so it's going to end up with the last value set. Perhaps you want to keep a `List` of the `CategoryModel` objects instead?

Comment: @MikeM. loke at the edit, I Added an ArrayList of CategoryModel but the question now how to get the Ids of each tab on select

Comment: `TabLayout` has the `OnTabSelectedListener` interface. In its `onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab)` method, the `Tab`'s `getPosition()` method can be used with that `ArrayList` to get the `CategoryModel` you want. Alternatively, `Tab` offers a tag property through `setTag()`/`getTag()`, so you could instead set the corresponding `CategoryModel` object as that tag on each `Tab`. Again, you'd use an `OnTabSelectedListener`, but depending on your setup, you might be using it indirectly; e.g., through a `ViewPager`'s listener.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you very much for your help and reply to me, I solved it by somehow

Answer (score 0):

There may be an exception raised why trying to parse the JSON, preventing tabs to be added.

Moreover As said by @Mike M. , you have `catId = categoryModel.getId();` INSIDE the loop, therefore, retaining only the last instance.

Use lists if you need all ID, and for debugging purposes, i'd suggest you to remove the try-catch syntax in order to be sure that the loop is fully executed without exception raised, or clarify your question saying that no exception is raised.